# How to retrieve the dynamically generated or repeated field values in a php file?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, dynamic-forms

I have a form as follow.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    <div class="add_another">

        <label for="BrotherAdmissionNumber" class="p-label-required">Admission Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="BrotherAdmissionNumber[]" placeholder="Admission Number"  />

        <label for="varName" class="p-label-required">Name</label>
        <input type="text"  name="BrotherName[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />

        <label for="BrotherGrade" class="p-label-required">Grade</label>
        <input type="text" id="varGrade" name="BrotherGrade[]" placeholder="Grade" class="form-control" />

        <label for="BrotherClassTr" class="p-label-required">Class Teacher</label>
        <input type="text" id="varClassTeacher" name="BrotherClassTr[]" placeholder="Class Teacher" class="form-control" />

        <button class="btn add_field_button" style="float: right;">Add Another Brother</button>

    </div>
    <button class="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I am using following jQuery to add another section to the form.
This will create the set of fields again.

```
<script>
var max_fields = 10;
var wrapper = jQuery(".add_another");
var add_sec_3 = '<div class="add_another" style="border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0; border-spacing: 7px;"><label for="BrotherAdmissionNumber" class="p-label-required">Admission Number</label><input type="text" name="BrotherAdmissionNumber[]" placeholder="Admission Number"  /><label for="varName" class="p-label-required">Name</label><input type="text"  name="BrotherName[]" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" /><label for="BrotherGrade" class="p-label-required">Grade</label><input type="text" id="varGrade" name="BrotherGrade[]" placeholder="Grade" class="form-control" /><label for="BrotherClassTr" class="p-label-required">Class Teacher</label><input type="text" id="varClassTeacher" name="BrotherClassTr[]" placeholder="Class Teacher" class="form-control" /><a href="#" class="remove_field btn" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Remove</a></div>';

jQuery(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        jQuery(wrapper).append(add_sec_3); //add section
        jQuery('.add_another .add_another:last').hide();
        jQuery('.add_another .add_another:last').show('fast');
    }
});
</script>
```

When clicking on add another button a section is added successfully.
So that's fine.

My issue is, I tried several methods of retrieving for arrays but nothing works.
I want to create another form with hidden fields of brother details to send it to another page.

How can I show the all generated fields values in a php page during the submission?

How do I have to update this *action.php* file?

**action.php**

```
<?php
$BrotherAdmissionNumber = $_POST['BrotherAdmissionNumber'];
$BrotherName = $_POST['BrotherName'];
$BrotherGrade = $_POST['BrotherGrade'];
$BrotherClassTr = $_POST['BrotherClassTr'];

foreach(){
    //brothers details start here
?>
<form action="action2.php" method="post">
    Admission Number :<?= $BrotherAdmissionNumber ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $BrotherAdmissionNumber ?>" name="BrotherAdmissionNumber" />

    Name :<?= $BrotherName ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $BrotherName ?>" name="BrotherName" />

    Grade :<?= $BrotherGrade ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $BrotherGrade ?>" name="BrotherGrade" />

    Teacher :<?= $BrotherClassTr ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= $BrotherClassTr ?>" name="BrotherClassTr"/>

    <button name="send_to_other_page">CONFIRM</button> <!-- when this button is clicked the form shoukd send the hidden values -->
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Now when *send_to_other_page* button is clicked the form should send the hidden values to next page *action2.php*

What I have to update in foreach loop above?
How I can collect these details in **action2.php** ?

Comment: implode array to string then store its value to hdden field

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

You have to serialise form data and then you can easily retrieve and save in database.